# How can I download price data given the ISIN?

Tags: stocks

Give the ISIN of a stock I would like to download the stock prices of, for example, the last 30 days. Is there a simple way to do this?

Requirements
- Must take the ISIN as input
- Should be available as simple web download (wget, curl) or via a simple python script